# Unused expression, expected an assignment or function call (Angular)

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm making a registration form in Angular.
I want to check if I have User's username and pass that value to the object if it is not null.

```
loadData(data: User) {
    data.username && (this.registrationData.username = data.username.trim());  
}
```

I am getting this error:
Unused expression, expected an assignment or function call (no-unused-expression)

Comment: What's with the mania for saving *literally two characters* by avoiding an `if` statement? Only in this case you don't save anything because you need `&&` and `()` which is the same length as `if` and `()`.

Answer (score 0):

It's telling you to not abuse `&&` as a replacement for `if`. Instead, use:

```
if (data.username) {
  this.registrationData.username = data.username.trim();
}
```

Or, consider:

```
const trimmed = data.username.trim();
if (trimmed) {
  this.registrationData.username = trimmed;
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to use it without if?

Comment: @urosmladenovic why? You don't have a single expression there, so what is the reason to avoid the statement?

Comment: It's possible, but it's a bad idea, because avoiding `if` obscures the intent of the code and makes it harder to read. That's why the linting rule exists. If you want to save characters from being sent in the `.js` to the client, leave that to *automatic* minifiers, while keeping the source code as readable as possible.

Answer (score 0):

That's a common [tslint rule](https://palantir.github.io/tslint/rules/no-unused-expression/) that requires you to not leave an expression (that is, a statement that produces a result) unused.

You can use an `if` statement like this:

```
loadData(data: User) {
    if (data.username) {
        this.registrationData.username = data.username.trim();
    }
}
```